# Jmeter Xpath Extractor JSON

Tags: json, xpath, jmeter

I'm trying to extract the parameter roomNo from the following JSON with JMETER XPATH Extractor:

```
*/
{   
"categoryCode": ["I4"],
"Response": {
    "class": "example",
    "availables": {
        "available": [
            {
                "Desc": " Middle",
                "roomNo": "5049"
            },
            {
                "Desc": " Middle",
                "roomNo": "5062"
            }
            ],
        "class": "test"
    },
    "advisoryInfo": null
},
"storeId": "10251"
}
*/
```

i use the following expression with no success:

```
/Response/availables/available[0]/roomNo
```

is the expression wrong?

---

UPDATE:

i'm try to use the plugins JSON PATH EXTRATCTOR. i tryied the following queries with no success:

```
$...available[0]

$.Response.availables.available..roomNo[0]

$.Response.availables.available[0].roomNo
```

---

UPDATE1:

one more consideration: the ajax response I recieve starts with */, is it possible this creates troubles with JSON EXTRACTOR? i see the response through view Results Tree

---

UPDATE2:
i try the following approach:

ajax request followed by bash extractor, followed by json extractor but it is still not working

in bash extractor i did as suggested using the following strings
    String temp = new String(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    prev.setResponseData(temp.replaceAll("\*/","").getBytes());

some more question:

*is it possible to see the result of bash extractor?*
*should i declare before json extractor that it should use temp variable? how?*

Comment: Thanks for `UPDATE1`, didn't realize that it's a part of response. JSONPath Extractor won't consume it, you'll need to remove them somehow.

Comment: It's possible to see variables values using Debug Sampler - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler I see `replaceAll("\*/","")`, please double check it. It should be escaped by additional slash as `replaceAll("\\*/","")` as replaceAll assumes regex

Comment: I finally used regex extractor

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid XPath Extractor won't let you parsing JSON.

You'll need [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) (you need **Extras with Libs Set**).

In your case relevant JSONPath query will look like:

```
$.Response.availables.available..roomNo[0]
```

Check out [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to **Parsing JSON**) for more information and XPath to JSONPath mappings table.

Hope this helps.

UPD. You can use Beanshell Post Processor to get rid of your `*/` bits, in that case JSONPath should work fine. Beanshell PostProcessor code:

```
String temp = new String(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
prev.setResponseData(temp.replaceAll("\\*/","").getBytes());
```

Make sure that Beanshell Post Processor goes **before** JSONPath Extractor.

Comment: Kindly see updated answer for workaround for your `*/` surroundings

Comment: Tryied the solution but still not working please see UPTDATE2